# Not able to connect to Oracle using Service Name

Tags: oracle

I have hit a strange problem where I am not able to connect to Oracle as normal -
username@service, and then type in the password.

When I do follow this pattern I get the following error - ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.

If I type in with username/pwd@hostname/servicename it will connect. The tnsnames file is fine, it has never changed at all. It is also strange that this problem also exists not with one database, but with a couple of others.

Can anyone give me some direction for a solution?

Comment: set `ORACLE_SID` environment variable to `SID` of your database

Comment: on windows `set ORACLE_SID=mydb`

Comment: @Andy5, can you  provide the output of both ? and also if you run tnsping service_name . I guess you are connecting to a database remotely, don't you ?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to the database remotely over a closed network.. The output is the error message given above. tnsping service name says it cannot find the service. However, I probably didn't make it clear that when I connect to a database schema I have different schemas for different things. One of colleagues is suffering the same problem in his development envronment.

Comment: tnsping only indicates if a listener is present; it doesn't resolve service_name or SID. What operating system is your client, and are you running a local database there as well?

Comment: Your reported actions very much point to an invalid value in your tnsnames.ora.  You say it is fine but oracle disagrees, and my money is on oracle.  You need to show us the ouput of 'tnsping' and the output of 'lsnrctl status'.  That will definitively show what is being requested of the listener and what the listner knows.

Comment: Windows 10 is the os

Comment: Oracle is running off another server and I don't have direct access to it. So I can't advise on the listeners. However I have been told it uses scan listeners

Comment: Is this a RAC database? I tend to agree with @EdStevens, that your tnsnames.ora isn't correct somehow. Not sure how else to explain why a basic connection string works but a tnsnames.ora alias doesn't. Can you post your tnsnames.ora entry and the output from tnsping, as well as the basic connect string that you used? (Substitute hostnames to protect the innocent...)

Comment: It is a clustered database. However the tnsnames file has not changed in over 5 years and so has not changed. It is wierd that a colleague of mine is also suffering the same problem. Neither of us have changed anything. Could it be the scan listeners have failed?

Comment: When you connect using the TNS alias, is that defined in your tnsnames.ora with the same hostname (or cluster name), port and service name you use for the working easy-connect method? It's possible it is using a different service name that has now been retired on the DB end,

Comment: Yes, the scan addresses are defined in the tnsnames file. The service names should not be removed as some of these schemes are in production

Comment: If the easy-connect is using hostname and tnsnames.ora is using specific SCAN IP addresses, then something has likely changed in the networking configuration. If you use nslookup on the cluster hostname, do you still get the same IP addresses returned that are used in the tnsnames.ora? You may have to call nslookup several times to get it to return all three SCAN addresses (especially on Windows). If not, then confirm with the DBA which IP addresses should be used, or update the tnsnames.ora file to use the cluster hostname instead of the IP addresses.